# mongodb limit operation retrieve newest docs

Tags: mongodb

mongodb find return docs by ascending order of "_id", when apply limit(n) on find(), it always return oldest n docs (Assume doc1's _id > doc2's _id imply doc1 newer than doc2, for example, the ObjectId ). I want let it return newest n docs so I do:

```
col.find().sort({"_id":-1}).limit(n)
```

Is this inefficient? Will mongodb sort all docs in 'col'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `_id` field is essentially the "primary key" and therefore has an index so there is not actually a "sort" on the whole collection, it just traverses that primary index in reverse order in this case.

Provided that you are happy enough that this does reflect your "newest" documents, and in normal circumstances there is no reason to believe otherwise, then this will return what you want in an efficient manner.

If indeed you want to sort by something else such as a timestamp or other field then just create an index on that field and sort as you have above. The general cases should use that index as well and just return in "descending order" or as specified in the direction of your sort or default index

```js
db.collection.ensureIndex({ "created": 1 })
```

Or as default "descending" :

```js
db.collection.ensureIndex({ "created": -1 })
```

Then query:

```js
db.collection.find().sort({ "created": -1 })
```

So basically it does not "sort" the whole collection when an index is present to use. The `_id` key is always indexed.

Also see [`.ensureIndex()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/) in the documentation.